# php - variable from a form - lack of special characters

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm aware there are many similar questions on this forum, but it's the 2nd day that I'm going through the answers and nothing seems to work.

It's my first week of PHP learning, so please try to answer in a simple way :) So:

I'm creating a conjugator and so far it's going well, but only if I don't use special characters. As Polish verbs are all about special characters, I'm stuck.

This code works (the conjugation is visible on the screen after pressing "submit"):

Page 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>Conjugator</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
    <form action="new.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" >
Conjugate: <input type="text" name="verb"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"');

$verb = $_POST['verb'];
$last2 = substr ($verb, -2);
$last3 = substr($verb, -3);
$last4 = substr($verb, -4);

$root2 = str_replace($last2, "", $verb);
$root3 = str_replace($last3, "", $verb);
$root4 = str_replace($last4, "", $verb);


    $nic = array("nie", "nisz", "ni", "nimy", "nicie", "nia" );    
    $gnic = array("gnije", "gnijesz", "gnije", "gnijemy", "gnijecie", "gnija");
    $ac = array("am", "asz", "a", "amy", "acie", "aja");

  if ($last3 == "nic" && $last4 != "gnic") {
    foreach ($nic as $one) {
        echo "<li>$root3$one</li>";
    }
}

elseif ($last4 == "gnic") {
foreach ($gnic as $one) {
echo "<li>$root4$one</li>";
}
}

elseif ($last2 == "ac") {
    foreach ($ac as $one) {
        echo "<li>$root2$one</li>";
    }
}
    ?>
```

But if I write for example:
       $nic = array("nię", "nisz", "ni", "nimy", "nicie", "nią" );
and then:
     if ($last3 == "nić" && $last4 != "gnic")
no result shows up.

For checking, try with verbs like "pienić" or "lśnić" (they don't work) or write them without the special characters ("pienic", "lsnic") - the first code will work.

Help will be deeply appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried applying utf8_encode() to your output?

Comment: which encoding has your source code file? if not utf8 then you have to utf8_encode() on output

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, could you make it more clear for me please? Where exactly shoud I put that code?

Comment: I'm working on Notepad++ and I set encoding to utf-8 without BOM, as suggested in many threads with this problem.

Comment: This should be helpful: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can't use substr() with UTF-8. It thinks in terms of *bytes*, not *characters*. Take a look at mb_substr().

Comment: All right, I'll do it now and let you know if it worked, thnx! (Sorry, can't vote up for your answer as it requires 15 points of reputation and it's my first question here).

Comment: Ok, so I read about it and I think you're right, but still it doesn't work. This is how it looks now:

    $last2 = mb_substr ($verb, -2, 'UTF-8');
    $last3 = mb_substr($verb, -3, 'UTF-8');
    $last4 = mb_substr($verb, -4, 'UTF-8');

Comment: mb_substr($input_string, $start, $length, $encoding). Take a look at php.net's manual entry. You can't skip the length if you're going to use the encoding.

Comment: Wow, Phil, it worked like a dream, big big thnx! Deceze - I'll definately take a look at that, thnx!